# Fedora and Ubuntu on the Same Volume Group

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, partition, lvm, luks

Can I install Ubuntu and Fedora on the same volume group of LVM. I wanted to do this as I could extend or compress a logical volume in a volume group and share the space with others.

I was going to have separate root and home logical volumes for both these operating system. And wanted to share boot partition, a logical volume for Data.

Any suggestions? Is it even possible to install like this if I could choose the logical volumes while installing?

---

## Edit

Steps that I think I should follow. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere:

1. Insert Ubuntu USB Stick and Try Ubuntu
2. In terminal create following partitions:

   - BootUbuntu
   - BootFedora
   - GRUB
   - EFI
   - rootfs

```bash
DEV="/dev/nvme0n1"

# sgdisk --new=1:0:+768M $DEV
# sgdisk --new=2:0:+768M $DEV
# sgdisk --new=3:0:+2M $DEV
# sgdisk --new=4:0:+128M $DEV
# sgdisk --new=5:0:0 $DEV

# sgdisk --typecode=1:8301 \
  --typecode=2:8301 \
  --typecode=3:ef02 \
  --typecode=4:ef00 \
 --typecode=5:8301 $DEV

# sgdisk --change-name=1:BootUbuntu \
  --change-name=2:BootFedora \
  --change-name=3:GRUB \
  --change-name=4:EFI-SP \
  --change-name=5:rootfs $DEV
```

3. Encrypt the *rootfs* Partition using LUKS
4. LUKS open the encrypted partition
5. In *rootfs* partition, create a volume group in the partition and following logical volumes

   - UbuntuRoot
   - UbuntuHome
   - FedoraRoot
   - FedoraHome
   - Data
   - Swap
6. Install Ubuntu using the Ubuntu GUI installer and choose the logical volumes UbuntuRoot, UbuntuHome, Swap  and partitions: EFI, BootUbuntu. And Reboot.
7. Insert Fedora USB Stick and try Fedora
8. Open the LUKS encrypted partition *rootfs*
9. Install Fedora using the Fedora GUI Installer (Anaconda) and choose the logical volumes FedoraRoot, FedoraHome, Swap and partitions: EFI, BootFedora. And Reboot.
10. Boot normally and hope that grub would give us option to choose between Fedora or Ubuntu.

---

I tool the partitioning scheme from [Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019 - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019). I don't want to encrypt the boot partition and just the partition that contains Volume group with all logical volumes.

1. In the above link, I don't know how to modify `sgdisk --hybrid 1:2:3 $DEV`  for my use case.
   Can you please suggest how to modify this? And if I am doing the steps correctly?
2. After selecting Operating system will I be able to enter the passphrase to unlock the *rootfs*?

Answer (score 0):

Putting different root volumes in the same VG: yes, that should work.

Using the same /boot partition: more likely to cause trouble, as every kernel update on either distro will trigger a regeneration of grub config.

I'd share the /boot/EFI partition (not much choice there: it needs to be shared by all OSes on the machine), but not /boot itself. No big deal, the typical space usage of a /boot is << 500 MB.

Comment: Thanks. Please see the edit at the bottom of the question. Would be nice if you can comment on that too.